# CSS Modules how to cascade from selector of another file?

Tags: css, webpack, less, css-modules

I have two files

tab.less
.

```
tab {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

and tabs.less

```
.tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid @grey;

    .tab {
        margin-right: 24px;
    }
}
```

The question is how to import selector from another file because now css-loader generates two different selectors what is good, but I need to tell it that there should be selector from another file.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just add all your css rules under the hood of the desired selector or just copy the selector you want and use it on an other file ?

Comment: @Korte because there are two different components in different folders.
what do you mean by copy selector?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [composition](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#composition).

tab.less

```
.tab {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

tabs.less

```
.tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid @grey;

    .tab {
        composes: tab from './tab.less';
        margin-right: 24px;
    }
}
```

Also check this article with most popular and useful cases with css-modules – http://andrewhfarmer.com/css-modules-by-example/#example-5-composition